# Relationship between Polarizability and Conductivity

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, solid-state-physics

I've seen in the literature the relation:

$\sigma (q,\omega) = \frac{i e^2 \omega}{q^2}\chi(q,\omega)$

where $\sigma$ is the conductivity and $\chi$ the polarizability.
However my attempt to derive it leaves me without the factor $q^2$. I have

\begin{equation*}J_{int} = \sigma E_{tot}\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}P = \epsilon_0 \chi E_{tot}\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}\rho_{int} = -\nabla \cdot P = -iq\epsilon_0 \chi E_{tot}\end{equation*}
in Fourier space. The continuity equation reads as:
\begin{equation*}iqJ_{int} = i\omega \rho_{int} = iq\sigma E_{tot}\end{equation*}
Relating the two through $\rho_{int}$ and cancelling $E_{tot}$ yields:
\begin{equation*}\sigma = -i\omega\epsilon_0 \chi\end{equation*}

Forgetting the difference between the units, where is the missing $q^2$? Is there an improper Fourier transform?

Answer (score 1):

Using the definition of the polarization is not valid in all dimensions.
Instead, since this is a general relation we wish to prove, we will only use
identities we know. By the continuity equation and the definition of $\sigma$, we get
\begin{equation*} \frac{q\sigma}{\omega} = \frac{\rho_{int}}{E_{tot}}\end{equation*}
but, by definition,
\begin{equation*} \rho_{int} = \chi \phi_{tot} \mbox{ and }E_{tot} = -iq\phi_{tot}\end{equation*}
Combining all three yields the relation between $\chi$ and $\sigma$ which is valid in all dimensions.